# preventDefault not working after fadeout then load then fadein new href content into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preventdefault

I've searched and serached and nothing really seems to answer what I'm looking for.

I'm pulling in html pages into a div.  I finally got it to fadeout, load new href content, then fade in the new content.  However, I can't get it to preventDefault on the link.

Here's my code.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var url = $(this).attr("href"); 

$('#container').css('display', 'none');

$('#container').fadeIn(1000);

jQuery('a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('a').removeClass('current');
$(this).addClass('current');    
$("#container").fadeOut('1000',function(){
$('#container').load(url);
}).fadeIn('1000');

        });

    })
```

Comment: What is `var url = $(this).attr("href");` doing outside the event?

Comment: Try `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#container').css('display', 'none').fadeIn(1000);
    jQuery(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#container").fadeOut('1000', function () {
            $(this).load(url).fadeIn('1000');
        });
    });
})`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  That code still allows the fadeout, load, and fadein to work (nicely coded, though); however, the links are still firing for the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this `fadeIn` inside the load callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loading = false;
    $('#container').css('display', 'none');
    $('#container').fadeIn(1000);

    $('a').click(function(e){
            if(loading) return false;
        e.preventDefault();
            loading = true;
        var url = $(this).attr("href"),
            cont = $("#container");  //cache selector
        $('a').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');    
        cont.fadeOut(1000, function(){
            cont.load(url, function() {
                cont.fadeIn(1000, function() {
                    loading = false;
                });
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: That still does the same thing, but when I click the link it's still fading out and fading in the current content.  Thanks for the response, though.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that if I remove the fadeout and fadein, the preventDefault does work.  So, it must be something with that.  Hmmm...

Comment: Actually, the retun false killed the linking in general.  Darn!  Getting close, though.